# How to process binary data on `user_input` or `user_output` in SWI-Prolog?

Tags: io, prolog, swi-prolog

I want to write a program in Prolog which processes  binary data. It shall operate in a UNIX fashion, i.e. if no arguments were given, it should read from `stdin` / [`user_input`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=streamalias) and write to `stdout` / [`user_output`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=streamalias) to act as *filter* in *pipes*.

As long as my data is textual, everything is running fine, but as soon as my data is binary, the output is weird and completely not what I expected, sometimes I get strange messages like `Illegal multibyte Sequence`. The same happens with streams which I opened using [`open/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=open/3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per default, `user_input` and `user_output` are set to `type(text)` and `encoding(X)` with `X` being the encoding of the platform derived from the environment. If you want to process binary data, you need to change the type of the stream to `type(binary)` or the encoding of the stream to `encoding(octet)`. You can do so by using [`set_stream/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=set_stream/2), like this:

```
:- set_stream(user_input, type(binary)).
:- set_stream(user_output, type(binary)).
```

or

```
:- set_stream(user_input, encoding(octet)).
:- set_stream(user_output, encoding(octet)).
```

For streams which you open yourself, you can also use [`open/4`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=open/4) instead, using i.e. `open(Filename, read,  StreamIn,`**`[type(binary)]`**`)` or `open(Filename, read,  StreamIn,`**`[encoding(octet)]`**`)`.

When what you're reading is really binary data, `type(binary)` is the preferred method.

Comment: It might be cleaner if you used the `type` option, which can be either `text` or `binary`.